# removing stop words and string.punctuation

Tags: python, nltk, punctuation

i can't figured out why this doesn't works:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string

with open('moby.txt', 'r') as f:
    moby_raw = f.read()
    stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    moby_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(moby_raw)
    text_no_stop_words_punct = [t for t in moby_tokens if t not in stop or t not in string.punctuation]

    print(text_no_stop_words_punct)
```

looking at the output i have this:

```
[...';', 'surging', 'from', 'side', 'to', 'side', ';', 'spasmodically', 'dilating', 'and', 'contracting',...]
```

seems that the punctuation is still there. what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It must be `and`, not `or`:

```
if t not in stop and t not in string.punctuation
```

Or:

```
if not (t in stop or t in string.punctuation):
```

Or:

```
all_stops = stop | set(string.punctuation)
if t not in all_stops:
```

The latter solution is the fastest.

Answer (score 4):

In this line change try changing 'or' to 'and' that way your list will return only words that are both not a stop word and are not punctuation.

```
text_no_stop_words = [t for t in moby_tokens if t not in stop or t not in string.punctuation]
```

Answer (score 1):

Close. 
You need to use `and` not `or` in your comparison.
If it turns out a punctuation mark like ";" is not in `stop` then python won't check if it in `string.punctuation`.

```
text_no_stop_words_punct = [t for t in moby_tokens if t not in stop and t not in string.punctuation]
```